# Nested LOOP automation

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a workbook with 2 sheets in Excel and I need to make a small automation update with a macro VBA:

1. From 1 sheet I need to update information to the second sheet
2. I have made a Nested Loop and I loop through each row from my column and I check if the value is present in the second sheet and if is not I want to putt it in the last empty cell.

My code is below, but it is not working and I don`t know what is the problem.

```
Sub Update()

  Dim Final As Worksheet
  Dim Actual As Worksheet
  Dim rowCount, colCount As Integer
  
  ' Set worksheet
  Set Final = Worksheets("Final")
  Set Actual = Worksheets("Actual")

  'Init counter of rows
  rowCount = 2

  Do While Worksheets("Actual").Cells(rowCount, 1).Value <> Null
       colCount = 1
         Do While (Actual.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value <> Final.Cells(1, colCount).Value) _
           Or (Final.Cells(1, colCount) <> Null)
             If Final.Cells(1, colCount) = Null Then
               Final.Cells(1, colCount) = Actual.Cells(rowCount, 1)
            End If
            colCount = colCount + 1
         Loop
         
rowCount = rowCount + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did `Roles.cells` come from? From the question, shouldn't that be `Actual.cells`, or are you checking a different sheet here?

Comment: Also I'm not seeing anything that makes `colCount` increase at all? There should be a line to say `colCount = colCount + 1` somewhere in that inner loop.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes please review the code now, as you say I putt also increment for colCount butt is not working.

Comment: I think the inner loop is kind of conflicting with itself - there's a line saying `If Final.Cells(1, colCount) = Null` when that condition was ruled out by the `Do While` literally 1 line above. Try 'stepping into' your code (hit F8 repeatedly so it executes 1 line at a time) and see if that `If` statement ever triggers, and if so is it in the right place. EDIT: @Nacorid 's comment is right too, so `=Null` wouldn't have worked even if the lines weren't contradictory

Comment: `Null` is not what you are looking for. Either use the `isEmpty()` function or check against `vbNullString`

Comment: I replace condition Null with isEmpty() and is same result.Butt when i run the code manualy appplication is running just DoWhile condition and after that is going to End Sub and that`s it.

Comment: Your `while` condition is false only when `Actual.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = Final.Cells(1, colCount).Value` AND `Final.Cells(1, colCount) = Null`, implying that `Actual.Cells(rowCount, 1).Value = Null`, which you've already checked for. I'm surprised your code even runs at all!